# Why does ecrecover() take signature parameters (v,r,s) instead of the full signature?

Tags: solidity, signature, cryptography, ecrecover

Is there any reason `ecrecover()` takes the (`v`, `r`, `s`) signature parameters instead of the full signature, given that these can be easily computed inside the function itself?

I am asking because developers usually need to compute these parameters from the full signature each time they need to use `ecrecover()`, which seems like an unnecessary repetitive process that could've been mitigated had `ecrecover()` took the full signature instead.

Comment: very valid question imo! btw OpenZeppelin has an helper for that now OpenZeppelin has a helper contract for that now: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol

Answer (score 1):

Signatures typically use `v` to store the signature and `r`,`s` to store the hashed data. I agree that using ecrecover adds extra complexity and by adding approve/transferFrom we get a bit of anonymity because we allow a 3rd party to extract tokens from our balance for a fee, usually in WETH or something similar.

People say that if we use `signatures` we become `anonymous` which is totally false since nothing is truly hidden on ethereum. More on that topic you can find out from here: https://medium.com/swlh/ethereum-aint-hiding-your-secrets-703e89088937

Signatures are more broadly used to identify the user that use Metamask. We make our user sign something that either contains a source of random entropy or has already been secretly hashed with our private key and provide after that we check who the author of the new signature is and provide a temporarily session using ecrecover.

The exact approach can be found here:
https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/17/signing-and-verifying-messages-in-ethereum/

Also if you want a better & more detailed approach to signatures you can find our more by looking at how DreamTeamToken made their implementation here: https://etherscan.io/address/0x82f4ded9cec9b5750fbff5c2185aee35afc16587#code 
It should be easy to update to Solidity 0.5 , if you have any struggles regarding this please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

v, r, s are parameters in [Ethereum transactions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1990/what-is-the-ethereum-transaction-data-structure). An Ethereum transaction is the serialization of these values. Ethereum libraries will and should have methods to serialize and deserialize transactions so finding the v, r, s values should be no harder than calling a deserialize/decode function on a signed Ethereum transaction, you shouldn't have to calculate these values yourself.

You should note that what we call a signature is actually 256 bits and is the combination of the r and s field. The v field only contains one bit of information about the signature and makes it possible to derive the public associated with the signature -- such that you don't need to include that in the signed transaction. [Understanding Ethereum signatures](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/64380/understanding-ethereum-signatures/64398#64398)